# Excel VBA Runtime Error '70': Permission Denied

Tags: excel, vba, permission-denied

Here's the VBA module script:

```
Sub ExportToTXT()
Dim wsData As Variant
Dim myFileName As String
Dim FN As Integer
Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
Dim path As String
Dim myString As String
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
path = "C:\Users\MiniMe\Desktop\GE2\"

For p = 7 To lastcolumn
  wsData = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, p).Value
  'If wsData = "" Then Exit Sub
  myFileName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, p).Value
  myFileName = myFileName & ".txt"
  myFileName = path & myFileName
  'MsgBox myFileName
  For q = 7 To lastrow
    myString = myString & " " & Cells(q, p)

    FN = FreeFile
    Open myFileName For Output As #FN
        Print #FN, myString
    Close #FN
  Next q
  myString = ""
Next p

End Sub
```

I am using a VBA module to export Excel columns into TXT files, but I am getting a runtime error 70 (Permission Denied). If I run the script over and over again, it results in a few more TXT files or characters in each TXT file, but still ultimately has the same error. Debug is showing that the error occurs at `Open myFileName For Output As #FN`. Since the Excel file contains massive amounts of data, I wonder if the VBA script is trying to move on to outputting the next TXT file in the loop without having finished outputting the current TXT file. That's just a guess, since I'm completely new to VBA and quite inept.

I've been trying to work the problem out on my own, but can't seem to overcome this obstacle. Any thoughts? A big THANK YOU in advance! It's for a really good cause.

Comment: You may need to check  `myFileName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, p).Value`  maybe it contains invalid characters or  is nothing

Comment: After the line `Close #FN` type `DoEvents`. Now Try again

Comment: Is it possible that there are duplicate names in your file list?

Comment: Add an error trap (`On Error Goto`), and show the filename in a message box (`MsgBox(myFileName)`) in your error trap. That should reveal to you, what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks you all so much! Well on my way to launching this! So excited!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open and close the file that many times. Either take it out of the the inner `q` loop or flush `myString` every so often. In the code the writing to text file is taken out of the loop.

```
Sub ExportToTXT()
  Dim wsData As Variant
  Dim myFileName As String
  Dim FN As Integer
  Dim p As Long, q As Long
  Dim path As String
  Dim myString As String
  Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
  
  lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastcolumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  path = "C:\Users\MiniMe\Desktop\GE2\"
  
  For p = 7 To lastcolumn
    wsData = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, p).Value
    'If wsData = "" Then Exit Sub
    myFileName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, p).Value
    myFileName = myFileName & ".txt"
    myFileName = path & myFileName
    'MsgBox myFileName
    myString = ""
    For q = 7 To lastrow
      myString = myString & " " & Cells(q, p)
    Next q
    FN = FreeFile
    Open myFileName For Output As #FN
    Print #FN, myString
    Close #FN
  Next p

End Sub
```

Edit: `p` and `q` declared as `Long` following correction from @Tim Williams and `Write #FN, myString` changed to `Print #FN, myString`

Comment: This resolved the issue. I am so grateful!!! Now I just need to figure out which variable is causing my overflow error. I have 40,000 rows, and it seems I have a variable maxing out at 32,767. I have `Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long`, but that doesn't seem to prevent it. Thoughts, or should I ask as a separate question? Regardless, thank you so much!

Comment: @jdgieschen - q is declared as Integer.  There's no reason not to use Long wherever you might be tempted to use Integer.

Comment: Wow. That's what I needed to hear. It worked. This is AMAZING!!! I can't wait! Thank you!